# System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException, abc in in conceptual side annot be mapped to type 'System.Enum' on the object side

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

Have spent hours on this error and still couldn't figure out the cause.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException: 'Type 'abc.Database.Enum' in
>   conceptual side  cannot be mapped to type 'System.Enum' on the object
>   side.  Both the types must be abstract or both must be concrete
>   types.'

[image]

What I am doing

1. use db first approach. db class model is built upon actual database
2. create a custom dbcontext class based on default dbcontext class. the custom class takes a parameter.

Eg

```
public class TestDbContext:DbContext 
{
    public TestDbContext(string connection) : base(connection) 
    {
    }
    public DbSet<user_menu> user_menus { get; set; }
}
```

4. create a testDBContext object using a database name as argument, find the dbset and change/save the result to a list using ToList().
5. pass the saved list to view.

The error would throw at step 4.

Things I have tried:

- reconstruct the db model class
- reconstruct the custom dbcontext class
- delete bin/obj folder, clean solution and rebuild.

None of the above methods work.

Hope someone can shed some lights into this one. 
Thanks

Comment: Dont paste images of code, its not only annoying and makes us click on your image and leave your question, we cant copy and past it to test

Comment: thanks. i should use code sample {} right?

Comment: yeah 4 spaces before each line makes it a code block, or the sample button indents it all

Answer (score 0):

Cannot believe I spend two days on this. Basically what happened is that there is a typo in one of model of the dbset returned from dbcontext. I accidentally set one of the property in the model to be enum. Changed it back to string type and worked. 
The error message is a little bit vague in terms of providing hint on where to look at things but it is a good lesson for me. I found the issue by searching against "enum" against the entire project.